# How do different definitions of ellipse translate to the same thing?

Tags: definition, conic-sections

There are 2 definitions of an ellipse that I know.

One definition goes:

> The locus of a point moving in a plane such that the ratio of its
>   distances from a fixed line (directrix) and a fixed point (focus) is a
>   constant and less than 1.

Another goes:

> The locus of a point moving in a plane such that the sum of its
>   distances from two fixed point is a constant.

Now my question is how is it that these two definitions, which seem quite a lot different from each other, define the same thing - ellipse? One more thing I'd like to know is that in the first definition, only *one* fixed point and only *one* fixed line are mentioned. Whereas in the second one, there's no mention of the fixed line and *two* fixed points are mentioned. And one of the properties of ellipse is that there are *two* focii and *two* directrices. Now all this is quite confusing to me. I know that they all define the same thing, ellipse, but I don't know how exactly ( heck, not even roughly! :D ) are these definitions equivalent.

Comment: The second definition is the one by Appolonius, the father of Conic sections. From the second definition, the first one can be derived as a property of the ellipse.

Comment: But then where do one of the fixed points pop off from the second definition? And how come suddenly there be 2 fixed lines in what we use in practice?

Comment: And, if the first definition can be derived as a property of ellipse, how do you know that only ellipses (whatever they are defined as) satisfy that? After all, for the property to become a definition, it must be a property of only the thing being defined, right?

Comment: Note that in the first definition, I have mentioned that the constant ratio is < 1. So it defines only ellipses.

Comment: Starting from one we can reach the other.

Comment: An ellipse has two foci, not one. An ellipse also has two directrices instead of one. The 2 fixed points are the foci, the variable point makes the ellipse according to def 2. Now with the distance formula and some algebra, you can obtain a polar equation that satisfies the first property. The ratio in def 1 is called the eccentricity.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Can you please show how?

Comment: @imranfat, I know that the ratio is called eccentricity. Secondly, if the first one is to be a definition, I should be able to generate an ellipse just using that, right? So, can you show how is that possible?

Comment: @ParthThakkar, have you seen my answer?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, actually just seeing. Didn't get any time since I last posted any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, pick a point $(f,0)$ on the $x$-axis and a vertical line $x=L$ with $L>f>0$.

Let us consider all points $(x,y)$ such that this ratio is a constant $e<1$:

$$\frac{{\rm dist}({\rm point}\,(x,y),\,{\rm point}\,(f,0))}{{\rm dist}({\rm point}\,(x,y),\,{\rm line}\,x=L)}=\frac{\sqrt{(x-f)^2+y^2}}{|x-L|}=e.$$

Squaring yields

$$x^2-2fx+f^2+y^2=e^2x^2-2e^2Lx+e^2L^2$$

$$\iff (1-e^2)x^2+2(e^2L-f)x+y^2=e^2L^2-f^2.$$

We can slide the point $(f,0)$ and line $x=L$ along the $x$-axis without changing the shape or size of the resulting curve; these only affect its location. Thus we can without loss of generality move them so that $f=e^2L$. (Suppose $f$ and $L$ are distance $d$ apart: then simply solve $f=e^2(f+d)$ for $f$.)

At this point we have $(1-e^2)x^2+y^2=e^2L^2-f^2$. Dividing, we obtain

$$\frac{1-e^2}{e^2L^2-f^2}x^2+\frac{1}{e^2L^2-f^2}y^2=1,$$

which is of the form $\square x^2+\square y^2=1$, an ellipse. Conversely, let

$$b^2=e^2L^2-f^2,\qquad a^2=\frac{b^2}{1-e^2}$$

(note the condition $f=e^2L$ forces $f,e,L$ to have exactly two degrees of freedom), hence

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

is the general form of ellipse obtained. Working backwards (solving for $e,f,L$ in terms of $a,b$ under the condition $f=e^2L$) yields the focus and directrix of an ellipse. Note these ellipses are specifically those with center $(0,0)$ that are longer horizontally than vertically; every other ellipse can be obtained by performing rigid motions on the situation we've analyzed.

Similar work shows that $e=1$ defines a parabola, and $e>1$ a hyperbola.

If we view the equation $(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2=1$ as a midpoint between the two definitions, this answers half your question: how the first definition always generates an ellipse, and how every ellipse falls under the first definition. lab's answer connects this midpoint to the second definition.

<strike>With your powers combined, I am</strike> Together, these show that the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know how to get the ellipse equation from the first definition, although I had tried a lot. And here's a nice solution to it. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 2):

WLOG, we can assume the equation of the ellipse to be $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$ and any point on it can be written as $P(a\cos t,b\sin t)$

Let the foci be $S(ae,0), S'(-ae,0)$

So, $|PS|=\sqrt{(ae-a\cos t)^2+(0-b\sin t)^2}$
$=\sqrt{(ae-a\cos t)^2+a^2(1-e^2)(1-\cos^2t)}$

$=a(1-e\cos t)$ as $e\cos t<1$ $0<e<1$ and $-1\le \cos t\le1$

Similarly, $PS'=a(1+e\cos t)$

So, the sum of the distances is $2a$ which is independent of $t,$  hence constant and in fact equals to the length of the major axis.

Conversely,

WLOG we can assume the fixed points be $S(a,0)$ and $S'(-a,0)$ where $a>0$

So, $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-0)^2}+\sqrt{(x+a)^2+(y-0)^2}=2c$(say)

Observe that  the shortest distance between $S(a,0)$ and $S'(-a,0)$ is $a-(-a)=2a$

So, $2c$ must be $>2a\implies c>a$

On sqauring & re-arrangment we get , $$\frac {x^2}{c^2}+\frac{y^2}{c^2-a^2}=1$$ which is a standard equation  of an ellipse as $c>a$

Comment: You answered how the 2nd definition translates to the equation but not how the first one gives the ellipse equation. But that part was answered anyway by anon (who didn't answer how the 2nd definition gives the ellipse equation)!. But thanks a lot, seriously! This was a big doubt that had been bugging me since roughly 6 months - since I learnt the basics of conics! You and anon together gave a solution, finally !! Thanks again :D

Comment: @ParthThakkar, have you seen the first half of the answer. We know the fixed line(directrix) here are $x=\pm \frac ae$ and the foci are $(\pm a\cdot e,0)$ where the eccentricity $e=\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}<1$

Comment: The thing is, *they are* the fixed line*s*. One of my major concerns was how come suddenly a second directrix pop up in the properties of ellipse, since in its definition (1st), only one directrix existed. That's why I said you answered how 2nd def. gives the ellipse equation.

Comment: @ParthThakkar, we are free to consider exactly one element each from the two sets

Comment: Huh? I don't get you.